# Show alert when clicking on an inject li

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function which generates new `<li>`s inside a `ul`.

I would like to have an alert created on the page when the newly injected (or latest) `<li>` is clicked.

How could I achieve this?

Code:

```js
addLi = function() {
  let ul = document.getElementById("list");
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let children = ul.children.length + 1
  li.setAttribute("data-id", children)
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Umpteenth # " + children));
  ul.appendChild(li)
}


showAlert = function() {
  alert("Clicked!");
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li data-id="1">First</li>
  <li data-id="2">Second</li>
  <li data-id="3">Third</li>
</ul>

<button class="add" onclick="addLi()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have the event listener only be on the last item in the list, not on all newly created list items. To do that, you could do something like this:

```js
addLi = function() {
  let ul = document.getElementById("list");
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let children = ul.children.length + 1
  li.setAttribute("data-id", children)
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Umpteenth # " + children));
  ul.appendChild(li)
  
  // Remove event listener from current last item
  document.querySelectorAll("li")[document.querySelectorAll("li").length - 2].removeEventListener("click", showAlert);
  
  // Add event listener to new last item
  document.querySelectorAll("li")[document.querySelectorAll("li").length - 1].addEventListener("click", showAlert);
}

showAlert = function() {
  alert("Clicked!");
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li data-id="1">First</li>
  <li data-id="2">Second</li>
  <li data-id="3">Third</li>
</ul>

<button class="add" onclick="addLi()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li.addEventListener('click',showAlert)
```

Add event listener to created `li`

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener to newly created object, before appending it to the DOM.

```js
addLi = function() {
  let ul = document.getElementById("list");
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let children = ul.children.length + 1
  li.setAttribute("data-id", children);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Umpteenth # " + children));

  // added EventListener to the li object
  li.addEventListener("click", showAlert);
  ul.appendChild(li);

}


showAlert = function() {
  alert("Clicked!");
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li data-id="1">First</li>
  <li data-id="2">Second</li>
  <li data-id="3">Third</li>
</ul>

<button class="add" onclick="addLi()">Add</button>
```